# Want to use ANT landscape generator, where is it?

Tags: add-on, installation

I just downloaded Blender and am going to use it to generate landscapes.  I saw references to ANT landscape generator, but have no idea how to activate it or download it.

One video supposedly showed how to activate it, I found it but there was no activate check box shown.  Do I have to download it?

One site said it was included with Blender.  If so, where is it located because for the life of me I cannot find it anywhere and am getting frustrated.  I just want an easy way to generate landscapes(mountains, etc).

I searched the Blender file location (ProgramFiles\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons) with no success.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jim Lawrence

Comment: Literally 2 seconds of google searching https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape and https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?115302-HELP!-Where-is-the-ANT-Landscape-creator

Comment: You should have blender 2.78 or below to access the ANT Landscape . Thanks

Comment: @devdut That is simply not true. The A.N.T.Landscape add-on is included in the most recent release as well (2.79).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

User preferences > Addons > Add Mesh > A.N.T. Landscape.
It is in Blender, you only have to activate it.
If you cannot find it, try to download and reinstal Blender.

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/add_mesh_ant_landscape.py

Comment: I found the checkbox.  The youtube video showed it on the right side of the window.  It was actually on the upper left.  It is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: It's a little bit tricky. It shows up if you enter a.n.t in the search box (note the dots).